# QCustomPlot adding QCustomItemText

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget, qcustomplot

I am trying add a text item onto a `QCustomPlot` widget. The `QCPItemText` constructor takes a pointer to `QCustomPlot` widget as an argument.

> `QCPItemText::QCPItemText ( QCustomPlot *  parentPlot)`

After creating the `QCPItemText` object, it can added to the widget by using the member function, `QCustomPlot::addItem()`. But my problem is the program doesn't compile. It says there no member function called `QCustomPlot::addItem()`. But this [example](http://www.qcustomplot.com/index.php/tutorials/items) seems do this. I am confused.

This is part of my code;

```
    //hash out current widget
    QCustomPlot *currentWidget = GraphWindow::dynamicWidgetHash.value(slot);

   //Setup font
    QFont plotFont;
    plotFont.setStyleHint(QFont::Helvetica);
    plotFont.setBold(true);
    plotFont.setWeight(8);
    plotFont.setPointSize(16);

    GraphWindow::setupBackground(slot);        
    QCPItemText itemText(currentWidget);
    QString dataText = "No " + xLabel + " data found. \nPossibly the firm may not possess " + xLabel;
    itemText.setText(dataText);
    itemText.setPositionAlignment(Qt::AlignTop|Qt::AlignCenter);
    itemText.position->setType(QCPItemPosition::ptAxisRectRatio);
    itemText.position->setCoords(2,2);
    itemText.setFont(plotFont);
    itemText.setPen(QPen(Qt::white));
```

Where `dynamicWidgetHash` is a `QHash` object, which stores a `QCustomPlot *` for each given `key`.

The error occurs when I try to use this line

> `currentWidget->addIem(itemText);`

Answer (score 1):

On line 79 in the `changelog.txt` file, which exists in the `QcustomPlot` install path, you'll see that it reads:

> Removed `QCustomPlot::addItem`, not needed anymore as items now
>   automatically register in their constructor.

So you don't need `currentWidget->addIem(itemText)`;